# Automatically make URLs clickable with formatted url title

Tags: asp-classic

I use the below code to automatic create links in my strings. But how do I convert a link like:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

into:

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">stackoverflow.com</a>`

As it is now, the output is:

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</a>`

Thanks in advance!

```
Function create_links(strText)
    strText = " " & strText
    strText = ereg_replace(strText, "(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[^ ,""\s<]*)", "$1<a href=""$2"">$2</a>")
    strText = ereg_replace(strText, "(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ ,""\s<]*)", "$1<a href=""http://$2"">$2</a>")
    strText = right(strText, len(strText)-1)
    create_links = strText
end function

Function ereg_replace(strOriginalString, strPattern, strReplacement)
    ' Function replaces pattern with replacement
    dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp
    objRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    ereg_replace = objRegExp.replace(strOriginalString, strReplacement)
    set objRegExp = nothing
end function
```

Comment: `objRegExp.replace(">http://", ">")` would get rid of the `http://` in the link text.  Adding the `>` to the replace statement should ensure that the href attribute isn't affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it using the following code:

```
Function create_links(strText)
    strText = " " & strText
    strText = MakeLink(strText, "http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?")
    create_links = strText
End function

Function MakeLink(txt, strPattern)
    Dim re, targetString, colMatch, objMatch
    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
      .Pattern = strPattern
      .Global = True
      .IgnoreCase = True
    End With 

    Set colMatch = re.Execute(txt)
    For each objMatch in colMatch
        matchedValue = right(objMatch.Value, len(objMatch.Value))
        if instr(matchedValue, "://") Then
        Else
            matchedValue = "http://" & matchedValue
        End If
        urlName = replace(replace(replace(matchedValue, "http://", ""), "https://", ""), "www.", "")
        If instr(urlName, "/") Then
            Arr = split(urlName, "/")
            urlName = Arr(0)
        End If
        urlName = UCase(Left(urlName,1)) & LCase(Right(urlName, Len(urlName) - 1))
        txt = replace(txt, objMatch.Value, " <a href=""" & matchedValue & """ target=""_blank"">" & urlName & "</a>")
    Next 
    MakeLink = txt
End Function
```